# Create link between observations clustered within village

Tags: stata

Hi I am trying to create dyad from households id clustered within villages with stata. My problem is I do not know how to use vlookup in order to have a list of households id linked to every household.

Comment: @Eric HB's answer underlines that there is very little information here. There is no real detail on anything technical. You don't give example data (structure, variable names, typical values) and you don't show what code you have tried. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for detailed advice of what is expected here.

Answer (score 1):

Without a bit more information this question is tough to answer, but some places you can look are first `tabulate` to see your data broken down by variables. Another place to check is the `bysort` and `gen` commands, these together will probably be the answer you're looking for, although it is tough to tell from the question. Finally, you may want to look into `encode` if your village variable is a string, you will get a unique id for each village using that command.